# Limit on serialized data for jquery ajax method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, post

Is there a limit on the length of data given through POST type **ajax** method of jquery?

I'm submitting a form in the background using ajax() method:

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: '<?=BASE_URL?>comenzi/save', dataType:'json', data:$('#theForm').serialize(), success: function(response) { ...
```

But some of the inputs are not being sent, can not be found in the POST.

Is there a limit for this data parameter, or I should look for another problem here?

**UPDATE:**
I've put out the form  to console in two different ways:

```
console.log($('#theForm').serialize());
console.log($('#theForm'));
```

On the second output, all of my inputs are there, but in the serialized output I could not find some of my inputs. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What input types are missing? What data do they hold?

Comment: here is the POST: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=MumKtFZ6

Comment: Is it possible to supply the HTML form as well? I realise it must be big...

Comment: ...and here are all the inputs: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=PJMmGpb7

Comment: I want the actual HTML, and preferably the JavaScript you use to post it (not just the actual $.ajax call).

Comment: the post is embedded in the question. The html is too big

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14329/discussion-between-ervin-and-anders-holmstrom)

Answer (score -1):

From the jQuery API documentation:

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string,
>   the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and
>   radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only
>   if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Does that help?

If you are working with files, or want to submit a number of forms via Ajax, I've found the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to work really nice.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have name attributes, and the checkboxes case is even ok, but in a very strange way it's not serializing some hidden inputs, but not all of them. Some of the hidden inputs are serialized and some not.

Comment: Unless you are only losing hidden inputs that are all at the end of the form, then I doubt it's due to some size-limit. Could you please supply the form code, either in your original post (if it's not too big) or a jsfiddle?

Comment: there are not only hidden inputs, there are simple text inputs as well. And I think they are on the beginning of the form. All of them...